# Does everyone have to drink the Kiddush wine?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kiddush, motzi-yedei-chovato

When making Kiddush, does everyone who is yotzei have to drink the wine or grape juice, or is merely hearing it enough?

In my experience, it appears that Friday nights everyone is careful to drink, while at the kiddush by Shabbos day, people will eat a piece of cake instead (or at least it appears that it's as a substitute).

So: Is there a requirement for everyone to drink wine on Friday nights and Shabbos?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/522/should-one-drink-from-the-leaders-cup-after-kiddush

Answer (score 11):

Having everyone drink kiddush wine at night is brought down in the [shulchan aruch 271:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=99&hilite=) and is based on the rosh in [the 10th perek of pesachim siman 16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14315&st=&pgnum=264http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14315&st=&pgnum=264) who, as interpreted by the [beit yosef in orach chaim 271](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=458), is basing himself on the [gemara in pesachim 106a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=106&format=pdf) where we see that those gathered also drank wine at the morning kiddush. But it has nothing to do with kiddush per se and you are more than yotzei as long as someone drank a shiur. The practice to drink has to do with partaking of all kosei bracha and this even applies to the kos used for bentching (see [shulchan aruch 190:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=619&hilite=)). The connection to all kosei bracha is made by tosfot there in [pesachim 106a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=106&format=pdf) and by the gra in [shulchan aruch 190:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=619&hilite=). It seems to me that this all ties in to the gemara in [brachot 51a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=51&format=pdf) where one of the eleven things mentioned about a kos shel bracha is giving the extras to your wife and kids.

Comment: However there is the shitta of the Mordechai which we don't pasken like who holds one is only yotzei if they drink by day kiddush (birkas haneinin)

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=175

Answer (score 5):

[*Shulchan Aruch* 271:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=99&hilite=) says that at night everyone should ideally, but is not required to, taste it. (See [*Mishna B'rura* :71](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=99&hilite=) for an exception.) The same would seem to apply by day (see [*Rama* 289](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=134&hilite=)). As always, for practical guidance, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) rather than relying on what you read here.